# What is the easiest way to construct 2D matrix using row vector?

Tags: python, matrix, 2d, row

I need to construct a 2D matrix knowing a row vector. What is the easiest way to construct this matrix?

[image: Matrix A]

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
A = np.zeros(3,3)
for i in range(0,3):
    A[i][:]= a[i:3]
```

Comment: the easiest way is to write it manually `A = [ [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]], [...], ...]` as you have it on image.

Comment: I have to find a way to automate this because the dimension of A is changing and this is part of the bigger code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `a[i+1:i+2] + b[:-1]` I move all elements right (in `b`) and I add new element from original `a` at the beginning

```
a = [0,1,2,3]

A = []

b = a[:] # first row without changes
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(b)
    A.append(b)
    b = a[i+1:i+2] + b[:-1] # in next row move right and add new element at the beginning 

print(A)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 0, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Wow. You are genius. Thank you so much for the help